# TypeError: family() missing 1 required positional argument: 'rebw'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, euclidean-distance

**Getting is error how can I fix it? Please help**

here is the complete Error which is showing me in Terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Family-tracking-system.py", line 843, in search
    self.family(euclidean_lare,euclidean_ntm,euclidean_mct,euclidean_lent,euclidean_rent,euclidean_lebnt,euclidean_rebnt,euclidean_mw,euclidean_nl,euclidean_nw,euclidean_rew,euclidean_lew,euclidean_ea,euclidean_lebw,euclidean_rebw )
TypeError: family() missing 1 required positional argument: 'rebw
```

'

**Here is the code!**

```
self.family(euclidean_lare,euclidean_ntm,euclidean_mct,euclidean_lent,euclidean_rent,euclidean_lebnt,euclidean_rebnt,euclidean_mw,euclidean_nl,euclidean_nw,euclidean_rew,euclidean_lew,euclidean_ea,euclidean_lebw,euclidean_rebw )

    def family(self,label,lare,ntm,mct,lent,rent,lebnt,rebnt,mw,nl,nw,rew,lew,ea,lebw,rebw ):
        families = pd.read_csv('fts.csv')

        data = families.drop('label', axis=1)
        X = np.array(data)
        y = np.array(families['label'])
        feature_list = list(families.columns)   

        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)
```

Comment: Your sending one less parameter in function call.That is the reason it is telling as missing parameter

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, can you please point me the exact position like in which line I am missing that parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, your missing send one parameter in

```
self.family(euclidean_lare,euclidean_ntm,euclidean_mct,euclidean_lent,euclidean_rent,euclidean_lebnt,euclidean_rebnt,euclidean_mw,euclidean_nl,euclidean_nw,euclidean_rew,euclidean_lew,euclidean_ea,euclidean_lebw,euclidean_rebw )
```

That is the reason it is showing error at below line and showing the last parameter `rebw` is missing

```
def family(self,label,lare,ntm,mct,lent,rent,lebnt,rebnt,mw,nl,nw,rew,lew,ea,lebw,rebw ):
```